# Generate function signature automatically in c++

Tags: c++, ide

I have a problem with generating functions its getting pretty tedious, copy and pasting i have around 400 functions.
What would be the easiest way to generate them automatically?
I was hoping to just type up IController.h and the rest would be automatically populated, If somebody could direct me to such a thing that would be great.

I have 4 seperate files.

```
IController.h
Controller.h
Controller.cpp
MockController.h
```

For example in the `IController.h` file  i have a function called `display`

```
class IController
{
 public:
 virtual void display(Gui* gui) = 0; 
}
```

`Controller` class would inherit from `IController` and the keyword virtual is removed and the =0.

```
class Controller : public IController
{
  public:
  void display(Gui* gui);
}
```

`Controller.cpp` will contain the definition

```
void Controller::display(Gui* gui)
{

}
```

And finally `MockController.h` will contain the following

```
class MockController : public IController
{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(display, void(Gui* gui));
};
```

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: This is definitely an IDE question. I would know a way to reduce the tedium in Visual Assist (but that's a non-free plugin for Visual Studio so unlikely to be what you are looking for).

Comment: *"keyword virtual is removed and the =0"*. you might use `override` too.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: At least for the mocks, you can probably use the mock generator: https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock/scripts/generator

Comment: Are other tools at your disposal? It would probably be easy with perl, awk; tedious with sed and a one-liner with python - assuming some experience with the chosen tool.

Comment: I can use any tool as long as it does the job.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I tried googlemock can't get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110486/generate-mock-class-with-python-google-mock?noredirect=1#comment96964571_55110486

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few days to figure things out, hope this helps somebody I managed to solved the problem above with the script i made shown below. gmock_gen.py currently does not work with python 3.7.2, I installed 2.7.13 and the script below works.

user only needs to generate code for the first interface class and all the other files are autogenerated.

```
import os

#read contents of IController.h
filename = "IController.h"
file = open(filename,"r")

#variables
flag = False
classheader = ""
mockheader = ""
classbody = None
header = []
classitems = []

#read each line in the file
for line in file:
    # if the class name has been found 
    if(filename[:-2] in line):
        flag = True
    # save all data before the calss name
    if flag == False:
        header.append(line)
    #
    if filename[:-2] in line:
        flag = True
        classname = filename[1:-2]
        line = line.replace("class ", "public ")
        classbody = "class " + classname + " : " + line

    # remove virtual = 0
    if "virtual" in line:
        line = line.replace("virtual","")
        line = line.replace(" = 0","")
        classitems.append(line)

classbody += "\n"
classbody += "{\n"
classbody += "  public:\n"

for x in classitems:
     classbody += x 
     classbody + "\n"

classbody += "};"

for x in header:
    classheader += x

classheader += "#include " + "\""  + filename + "\"" + "\n\n"
mockheader += classheader
classheader += classbody

#create controller.h file
f = open(filename[1:], "w")
f.write(classheader)

cppbody = ""

for x in classitems:
    temp = x.split(" ", 2)
    temp2 = temp[1] + " " + filename[1:-2] + "::" + temp[2].replace(";","{\n\n\n}\n")
    cppbody += temp2 

#create controller.cpp file
cppfilename = filename[1:-2] + ".cpp"
f = open(cppfilename,"w")
f.write(mockheader)
f.write(cppbody)


mocktemp = "Temp" + filename[1:]
mockfilename = "Mock" + filename[1:]

input = "python gmock_gen.py " + filename
os.system(input + " > " + mocktemp)

#create MockIController.h
with open(mocktemp) as f:
    with open(mockfilename, "w") as f1:
        f1.write(mockheader)        
        for line in f:
            f1.write(line)
```