# generate mock class with python google mock

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to generate a mock class automatically using the gmock_gen.py script with python 3.7.2.

here is `my IController.h` file

```
#include <iostream>

class Gui;   

class IController
{
public:
    virtual void display(Gui *gui) = 0;
    virtual void count(int val) = 0;

};
```

I made a python script called `controller.py`

```
import os

filename = "IController.h"
file = open(filename,"r")

flag = False
header = []
classheader = ""
classbody = None
classitems = []


for line in file:
    if(filename[:-2] in line):
        flag = True

    if flag == False:
        header.append(line)


    if filename[:-2] in line:
        flag = True
        classname = filename[1:-2]
        line = line.replace("class ", "public ")

        classbody = "class " + classname + " : " + line
        #print("class " + header + " : " + line)

    if "virtual" in line:
        line = line.replace("virtual","")
        line = line.replace(" = 0","")
        classitems.append(line)

classbody += "\n"
classbody += "{\n"
classbody += "  public:\n"

for x in classitems:
     classbody += x 
     classbody + "\n"

classbody += "};"

for x in header:
    classheader += x

classheader += "#include " + "\""  + filename + "\"" + "\n\n"
classheader += classbody

f = open(filename[1:], "w")
f.write(classheader)

cppfilename = filename[1:-2] + ".cpp"
f = open(cppfilename,"w")

mockfilename = "Mock" + filename[1:]

    print(filename)
print(mockfilename[:-2])

#os.system("python gmock_gen.py " + filename + " " + mockfilename[:-2])
os.system("python gmock_gen.py " + filename + " " + mockfilename[:-2])
```

I am getting this error when i run the `controller.py` on the command line.

```
    C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP>controller.py
IController.h
MockController
Got exception in IController.h @ Token('class', 50, 55) []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 706, in Generate
    token = self._GetNextToken()
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 908, in _GetNextToken
    return next(self.tokens)
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gmock_gen.py", line 31, in <module>
    gmock_class.main()
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\gmock_class.py", line 222, in main
    lines = _GenerateMocks(filename, source, entire_ast, desired_class_names)
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\gmock_class.py", line 129, in _GenerateMocks
    for node in ast_list:
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 720, in Generate
    result = self._GenerateOne(token)
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 743, in _GenerateOne
    return method()
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 1455, in handle_class
    return self._GetClass(Class, VISIBILITY_PRIVATE, None)
  File "C:\Users\rafael\Desktop\CPP\cpp\ast.py", line 1537, in _GetClass
    body = list(ast.Generate())
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about gmock_gen.py, but that code is not parsable as C++ since `Gui` is not declared anywhere. You probably need a forward declaration.

Comment: i added a forward declaration still the same problem.

Comment: the above code is working using python version 2.7.13